# The maximum values from the index positions of an multilist in Python

Tags: python

Consider an array of lists:

```
arrayoflists = [[2,4,5,6],[4,6,5,2],[7,9,7,5]]
```

The output of this maximum function looks like:

```
maximum = [7,9,7,6]
```

Is there any inbuilt function to perform this  in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Python's list comprehensions and the `max` function:

```
arrayoflists = [[2,4,5,6],[4,6,5,2],[7,9,7,5]]

maximums = [max([sublist[i] for sublist in arrayoflists]) for i in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`max`ing the corresponding values across the lists:

```
>>> [*map(max, *arrayoflists)]
[7, 9, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
>>> list(map(max, zip(*arrayoflists)))
[7, 9, 7, 6]
```

How it works:

- `zip(*arrayoflists)` converts rows to columns, like `(2, 4, 7)`, `(4, 6, 9)`, `(5, 5, 7)`, `(6, 2, 5)`.
- `map(max, ...)` computes `max` for each of those columns, like `7`, `9`, `7`, `6`.
- `list(...)` puts those results into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as no

np.max(arrayoflists, axis=0)
```

Outputs:

```py
[7 9 7 6]
```